# Changing logo on scroll using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have been stuck with my code to change a logo on scrolling using Vanilla JS (Without JQuery).

What I got from my devtool was this error:-

*Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('[object HTMLImageElement]') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.at {localhost}*

Can anyone spot where I went wrong with my code?

```js
const bigLogo = `<img src="images/redsbaby.svg" alt="Logo" />`;
const smallLogo = `<img src="images/r.svg" alt="Logo" />`;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const currentLocation = window.pageYOffset;
    if(currentLocation <= 0){
        document.getElementsByClassName('.div-logo').innerHTML = smallLogo;
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('.div-logo').innerHTML = bigLogo;
    }
})
```

```html
<html>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="div-logo flex-col justify-center items-center order-1 mx-16 mt-2 md:-mt-1 sm:-mt-0.5 xs:mx-10 xs:-mt-0.5">
   <img src="images/redsbaby.svg" alt="Logo" class="big-logo md:hidden sm:hidden xs:hidden" />
   <img src="images/r.svg" alt="Logo" class=" small-logo hidden md:block sm:block xs:block" />
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the current code, there are 2 issues.

The selector string argument passed to the `getElementsByClassName` method, does not need the `.` prefixed to the class name (we're only selecting by class here).

The other thing is, that this [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) won't return a single element.

`The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s).`

If there are multiple `.div-logo` elements on the page, you will need to loop over them to set the `innerHtml` individually.

```js
const logoDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('div-logo');
for (let i = 0; i < logoDivs.length; i++;) {
   logoDivs[i].innerHTML = smallLogo; // or bigLogo 
}
```

If there will only ever be one `.div-logo` element, just use `document.querySelector`.

```js
document.querySelector('.div-logo').innerHTML = smallLogo; // or bigLogo
```

Comment: If there's only one .div-logo, do we still need to loop through? In this case, I have 2 different logo that needs to be injected on the div-logo when scrolling

Comment: In that case I would just use your code as-is, but change document.getElementsByClassName() to document.querySelector()

Comment: Previous preferred, but you could also do: document.getElementsByClassName('div-logo')[0].innerHTML = smallOrBigLogo;

Comment: Yeah it's working now. But I need to refresh each time scrolling down to below Y-axis to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` returns an HTML element, which you're trying to add to another element's class list. This does not work since `classList` expects strings (CSS classes) and you're giving it HTML elements via `bigLogo` and `smallLogo`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I have changed my code to add an element to the div with a class of div-logo, but still not working